# Cursor on specific shape with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am making an app on Angular and I would like to do a custom cursor with this shape in CSS and HTML :

[image: Example]

I managed to do the curve in gradient, but I would like to have a round white cursor which follow the value in the center. For example here 70 is at the end of the curve (If it was 20 the cursor had to be at the beginning of the curve).

```
.main {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;

    &-current {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    &-minmax {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        bottom: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }

}
```

```
<div class="main">
    <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100" transform="rotate(138)">
        <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#2ed8a7" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#a6ceff" />
        </linearGradient>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" cx="50" cy="50" r="38" stroke="url(#linear)" stroke-width="8" fill="none"
            stroke-dasharray="275" stroke-dashoffset="100" stroke-mitterlimit="0" />
    </svg>

    <div class="main-current">70</div>
    <div class="main-minmax">
        <div>10</div>
        <div>100</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into `transform: rotate(...)` and `transform-origin` CSS properties to rotate the cursor on the path. The cursor itself could - for example - be implemented as a square `div` with `border-radius: 50%`.

To me, it seems most feasible to work with two nested elements. An inner one for the actual "cursor" (the round element), and an outer one, acting as the "hand on the clock" (shown in red below for illustration purposes).

[image]

The outer element can be positioned absolutely to the center of the shape (`top: 50%`, `left: 50%`) and be sized to take half the width of the shape. The `transform-origin` (`transform-origin: center left`) and the actual rotation (dynamic) would be set on the outer element, while the inner element (aligned on the right hand side of the "hand") just visualizes the cursor.

Comment: But how can you change the transform-origin to the center of the parent component ?

Comment: @Mo0nKizz You can use negative values in `transform-origin` to move the origin outside of the element, or use an additional wrapper element to simplify setting the `transform-origin`.  I have updated the answer to explain this approach in more detail.